# FBA _Layouts folder permission issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Just created a page in the _layouts folder on a site with FBA.  Whenever I try to access the new page, I get 'Access Denied".  How do I set permissions on a page in the _layouts folder?  It's fine with me is it's public and available.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood the question correctly. if not please feel free to comment

You can try using UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase to derive your page so that it is open for anon access. Try this link for more information
http://dishasharepointworld.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-create-sharepoint-application_1072.html

Cheers
VJ